# OnResume not being called in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

i go from one fragment to another fragment, when i press the back button and return to the previous fragment, that fragment's on resume is not being called. why is this? i provided the code i use to go to the second fragment. Any help?

```
                Frag2  pfrag = new Frag2();
                pfrag.setArguments(bundle);
                ft=fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.fragment_swap, pfrag,"Profile");

                ft.show(pfrag);

                ft.addToBackStack("pfrag");
                ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The onResume() for your fragment will only be called when the Activities OnResume() is being called.